# Univariate Time series clustering

Tags: time, cluster-analysis, series

I have a dataset of 3 columns
sample# time-stamp  one variable

I want to do clustering on the basis of this single variable. I don't understand how should I do it?

Comment: I suppose you have multiple time series?